# Stuck at solving T(n) problem using recursive relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

I am trying to solve the following
$T(n)  = 4T(n/2) + p*n $  where p is a constant, we may assume $ n = 2^k $

I took the general equation as $T(n)  = a*T(n/b) + g(n) $
Writing it recursively i came to the following function:
assuming i as the tree depth, first one is i = 1 listed above

$T(n)  = a^i*T(n/b^i) + \sum\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} a^k*g(n/b^k) $

so substituting the above equation we get:

$T(n)  = 4^i*T(n/2^i) + p\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} 4^k*(n/2^k) $

$T(n)  = 4^i*T(n/2^i) + p\sum\limits_{k=0}^{i-1} 2^k*n $

since the base case $ T(1) = constant $, then we can say
$1 = (n/2^i)$ 
taking log of both side
$log(2^i) = log(n)$
thus
$ i = log_{2}(n) $

putting it back into the equation we get:

$T(n)  = 4^{log_{2}(n)}*T(n/2^{log_{2}(n)}) + p\sum\limits_{k=0}^{log_{2}(n)-1} 2^k*n $
  simplifying it
$T(n)  = n^{2}*T(1) + p\sum\limits_{k=0}^{log_{2}(n)-1} 2^k*n $

since it says we may assume that $ n = 2^k $, if i put that into the equation:
$T(n)  = n^{2}*T(1) + p\sum\limits_{k=0}^{log_{2}(n)-1} n*n $, which in turn comes to:
$T(n)  = n^{2}*T(1) + p*n^2\sum\limits_{k=0}^{log_{2}(n)-1} 1 $, which comes to:
$T(n)  = n^{2}*T(1) + p*n^{2}*log_{2}(n) $
from this it looks as if $ p*n^{2}*log_{2}(n) $ is the dominant term, thus it comes to
$ O(n) = n^{2}*log_{2}(n) $, but according to the master theorem this should be $ O(n) = n^{2} $, i am not quite sure where i am making the mistake here.
Help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used $k$ in two different places.  Firstly, to say that $n$ is a power of 2, you say $n=2^k$.  Secondly, you use $k$ as the dummy variable to sum all the smaller powers.
In most of your calculations, $n=2^i$.  When you write "since it says we may assume $n=2^k$", you should have written $n=2^i$ instead.
Do you know what the sum $\sum_{k=0}^{i-1}2^k=1+2+...+2^{i-1}$ equals?